# Lload a contact image from contacts include facebook twitter etc - android

Tags: android, image, contacts

I have an android app that I show the contacts details include the contact profile image.
This is how I get the contact image:

```
Uri photo = null;
String sPhoto = cursor
.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_ID));
if (sPhoto != null) {
photo = Uri.withAppendedPath(person,ContactsContract.Contacts.Photo.CONTENT_DIRECTORY);
myImageView.setImageURI(photo);
```

This code works just fine when the image is taken from the phone, but in my phone (like many others) I have a facebook profile, twitter profile etc, and in my default dialer I can see the facebook or twitter profile image beside the contact name, or the normal image (from the phone)
My code is given me only the image that exists in my phone, How do I get all images include facebook or twitter if such images exists?
Thank you